# How do I implement contents of this github into my website? I don't know much about javascript

Tags: javascript, html, text-to-speech

I wanted to implement text to speech to the website I'm making and found this: https://github.com/petercunha/tts but I'm too much of a novice to know what to do with 
How do I implement it to my website?

Comment: Hi Veronika, that package says it's for NodeJS. You say you don't know much about javascript so perhaps it's not the best for you.

Comment: For only text to speech you can use the built in browser's Speech Synthesis API:
`var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("This is an example of speech synthesis."); window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);` - or, as a HTML button: `<button onclick="window.speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello World'))">Make Me Speak</button>`. Note that you need a user event (like mouse click or button press) to trigger speech - the browser won't let you start speech on page load.

Answer (score 0):

You got [option](https://www.instructables.com/id/Downloading-Code-From-GitHub/) in right corner of container with green box "clone or download"